# Menu disappears while navigating from one content page to another

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin App, with a Master Detail Page Layout and When I navigate to a content page from another content aPage. The menu disappears on the content page.

I have three pages: MasterDetailPage.xaml.cs, ListItemsPage.xaml.cs and DepositsPage.xaml.cs

MasterDetailPage.xaml.cs

```
// Constructor.
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Detail = new NavigationPage(new Login());
    IsPresented = false;
}
```

//Navigates to the content Page called ListItemsPage.xaml.cs

```
OnMenuItemSelected()
{
    Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ListItemsPage));
}
```

On Click of a List Item on the ListItemsPage → It should navigate to another content page (Deposits.xaml) and the following is the code I use:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DepositsPage());
```

It navigates to the page but the menu is missing.

I would really appreciate it, if somebody could help me with this as I have been struggling with this the last couple days.

Answer (score 2):

When using MasterDetailPage navigation whenever you want to navigate but keeping the menu on the side you have to navigate changing the `Detail` part as you did when you replaced your `Login` with `ListItemPage`but instead you are changing the whole Application page when you did `Application.Current.MainPage`

Something else I see in your code above is that you are not specifying the `Master` which is the part that should hold your Menu items.

Based on the Xamarin Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page) you should define your MasterDetailsPage in this way:

```
public MainPage()
{
    var menuPage = new MenuPage();
    Master = menuPage;
    Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ListItemsPage));

    menuPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnMenuItemSelected
}

OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
    if (item != null) {
        Detail = new NavigationPage ((Page)Activator.CreateInstance (item.TargetType));
        masterPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
        IsPresented = false;
    }    
}
```

But the above expects that your MenuPage will have a ListView where each item is a menu option containing all the information required to display the menu option and navigate.

```
public class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListView ListView { get { return listView; } }

    public MenuPage()
    {

        Icon = "hamburger.png";
        Title = "My great application";

        var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem> ();
        masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
        Title = "List Items",
        IconSource = "list_items.png",
        TargetType = typeof(ContactsPageCS)
        });
        masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
        Title = "Deposit",
        IconSource = "deposit.png",
        TargetType = typeof(TodoListPageCS)
        });

        ..........
    }
}
```

If you follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page) for this you should be good. If still with doubts come back here.

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that the title was missing.

After adding the title in to the content page everything worked like a charm…

Comment: No way in heven could that affect the shell